# what is the average total prioritization fee per slot currently

Tags: validator, slots, block

Curious if there are resources that I can use to get the average prioritization fee per slot or at least visualize them.

if not possible, then still interested in anecdotal data about what the average total prioritization fee per slot currently is.

Thanks Solana Community.

Comment: This might be helpful https://docs.solana.com/transaction_fees#:~:text=The%20prioritization%20fee%20is%20calculated,the%20compute%20budget%20instruction%20here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an analytics dashboard that shows how prioritization fees are being used on the network: https://dune.com/crypto_notte/solana-additional-fee-analysis